# python file executable not working on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, debian, glibc

I have a .py file (`camera.py`) that is programmed to capture image from a USB camera connected to the Raspberry Pi. The `camera.py` file is as below and is running as expected from Terminal of raspberry.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, image = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('Imagetest',image)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k != -1:
        break
cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/testimage.jpg', image)
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now I want to turn this `camera.py` file into a standalone .exe and here is where I am getting into trouble.
I have tried 2 ways to accomplish this; pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe GUI.
In both cases I have  received no issues while the .exe got built but when I click to run it, it does nothing (when I click 'Execute' as well as 'Execute in Terminal' - in the latter case a terminal window also doesn't open.)

When I try to execute the file manually from terminal with below commands:

```
chmod a+x camera
./camera
```

I get the below error:

```
./camera: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./camera)

./camera: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./camera)
```

My guess is the problem lies in version incompatibility with GLIBC so I have looked up the version installed and the highest available in my Debian 11 is 2.31

[image]

If it is really a glibc version problem, can you tell me how I can install the required version in my Debian 11 Raspberry. I guess there are issues with it given my google search.
If it is not the version incompatibility can you tell me what i should I correct.

**Create .desktop file Approach**

As per suggestions, i created a .desktop file (contents below) following this [documentation](https://linuxhint.com/run-python-script-desktop-icon-linux/). But still the program fails to launch the videostream. A window opens up momentarily but that's it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version= 1.0
Icon= /home/pi3/videorec.png
Name= videorec
Exec=//home/pi3/camera.py
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Comment: Do you build the package on the same architecture and OS than your Pi?

Comment: Why would you do this with a Raspberry Pi? It makes no sense: py2exe and similar make Python scripts _slower_ and more memory-hungry, and makes them require tmpfs space where they didn't before. There's no good reason ever to do this between a Debian system and a Raspberry Pi: they're both Linuxy systems where you can use proper packaging instead of needing ugly hacks designed with Windows users in mind.

Comment: I understand what you mean...My idea was to create a standalone exe on the Raspberry Pi desktop that can be run with on one click instead of opening the terminal and running it with the python command.  But now that I know the incompatibility issue, I guess that is the only option I have

Comment: `chmod +x camera.py` should do. Then check `ls -l`

Comment: You don't need an exe file to be able to run things by clicking them.

Comment: what do you suggest? My motivation is to create some sort of a shortcut that I can simply run from the desktop of my raspberry pi without having to open a terminal, navigate to folder where program is and run it with the python command. I have tried creating a .desktop file too but that approach is also not working

Answer (score 1):

You can't really upgrade glibc without causing a monumental cascade of ripple effects. The better solution is to build the binary on the correct platform in the first place; then it will bind to the same glibc etc versions.

In other words, get the Python script running on your target machine,  perhaps in a virtual environment (or e.g. a Docker image running the target OS), then run `py2exe` or whichever tool you prefer in that environment to produce a compatible binary.

However, this begs the question why you want to distribute your script in binary form anyway. A more portable solution would be to package it into a regular Python package, and have users install it with `pip`. This allows them to use it on any platform where Python and the libraries your script depends on are available.

To simply create an icon which allows you to run the script, create a `.desktop` file for it.  See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/342950/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-entry-to-launch-a-python-script

Comment: I do not wish to distribute the script as such. My reason for a standalone exe was to create an exe out of my script and place it on desktop of my Raspberry so that one can simply run it like an app with one click, instead of going to the terminal, then navigating to respective directory where script is and finally running it with the python command. Now that you know what I wish and avoid to do, are there any suggestions?

Comment: Just create a `.desktop` file which contains the command you'd type in the terminal.

Comment: I have tried this approach and edited my question. Like my edit mentions program still doesnt work. However a window seem to momentarily open.

Comment: The double slashes look wrong, but not hopelessly so. Does that command work if you run it while your current work directory is `/` (which is where I am guessing your desktop environment will run it)? If not, probably wrap it with a script which moves to the right directory, and/or activates the virtual environment, and/or what else needs to be done to run it properly.

Comment: The desktop environment for me is: home/pi3/Desktop..so should I change the execution line to: Exec= cd ..;python camera.py ?

Comment: Something like that is what I am suggesting, but the details are probably incorrect. Your question doesn't contain enough details to tell what exactly should work. Maybe try `Exec=python /home/pi3/camera.py` if that's what works on the command line. If it doesn't, tell us what exactly works when you are not in the directory where the script is saved.

Comment: HA! That worked...I needed to change the executing command to python /home/pi3/camera.py